# Drupal 7 Display Hit / Page View counter

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, counter

I want to display a counter on my website. 
The counter is to be done using Drupal, not by external providers. On the net I've found these instructions:

> Drupal 7 - Hit/Page View counter for Articles
>   Another task I had to spend more time that I needed to. You would think that a simple hit counter would be a readily availble in a modual. Anyway, heres what ya do:
>
> 1) It's part of core; enable the core "Statistics" module. You can see the official notes at : http://drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced
>
> 2) Go to: Administration » Configuration » System » Statistics. You may have to enable the "Statisctics" modual first.
>
> 3) For the setting "Content viewing counter settings" check the "Count content views" checkbox.
>
> 4) Be sure to set permissions for the module at admin/user/permissions, and configure it in admin/settings/statistics.
>   IMPORTANT - On the giant Permissions panel, scroll down to the "Statistics" mod and enable permissions for "anoymous user" and "authenticated user"
>
> 5) You can now show the total count of the page hits, it should display in the block region you assigned.
>
> IMPORTANT - The block name is called "Popular Content". Dont ask why.
>   You can see it working below:
>
> 5399 reads

I moved the popular content block into the correct region but it will not show me the number of hits only the most popular content pages. I would like to be able to show the number of hits.

Alternatives? 
How about a php-script?
But where to put it: http://my-drupal-site.com/...path???.../counter.php
What is the html-code to run the script and to show the result?

(Please if you reply be aware of: I am drupal newbie,
 experience status:
 php: no
 html, css, linux, bash programming: yes)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [visitors module](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) to display the amount of visitors.

The module provides the following blocks:

- Total Visitors.
- Unique Visitor.
- Registered Users.
- ...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. I have got the unique visitor count per node using "nodeviewcount.module". Just install this "nodeviewcount.module" module and then in my page.tpl.php I just fetched the result with the below code.

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) FROM {nodeviewcount} WHERE nid='.$node->nid;
$unique_visitors = db_query($query)->fetchField();
print $unique_visitors.' views';
?>
```

I think this might help you.